# how to use LIMIT in discontinuous data?

Tags: sql

I have a sql query like the following

```
    mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM students1
WHERE
(
    PartCode = '$s1' 
    AND (ElectiveSubject1='$s11' 
        OR ElectiveSubject2='$s11'
        OR ElectiveSubject3='$s11')
)
OR
(
    PartCode = '$s2'
    AND (ElectiveSubject1='$s22'
        OR ElectiveSubject2='$s22'
        OR ElectiveSubject3='$s22')
)
ORDER BY AdmitCode, RollCode LIMIT 5, 8");
```

it returns first 8 rows starting from 6th. But I need the rows from 6 to 13 and from 65 to 69 as a single set, ie I have to combine `LIMIT 5,8` and `LIMIT 64, 5`.

How to do this?

Comment: It looks like you need to do two SELECTs, instead of using OR, and UNION them.

Answer (score 0):

So this question can be marked as having an accepted answer, I'll repeat what I said in a comment:

Use two SELECTs, instead of using OR, and UNION them.